# Get related objects for specific user - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Some users are "coders" which have "assignments".

```
class Coder(models.Model):
    """Every user can be a coder. Coders are assigned to Assignments"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='coder')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username

class Assignment(models.Model):
    """An assignment covers a range of years, 
    has multiple coders and one specific task"""
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=1, related_name='assignments')
    coders = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assignments')
    screening = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    classifying = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.country
```

If a coder is logged in, how do I show them all the assignments that have been given to them?
The following view does not work, it gives me "'Coder' object has no attribute 'assignments'".

```
def user_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        assignments = request.user.coder.assignments.all()
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'account.html')
```

Why doesn't this work?
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.user.coder.assignments.all()`.

You are not passing the assignments in your call to render

Comment: doesn't work, sadly. 
"'Coder' object has no attribute 'assignment_set'" is the error I'm getting. If I use "assignments" instead of 'assignment_set' I don't get an error but I don't see the assignments in the template either...

Comment: You are not passing the `assignments` in your call to `render`.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the related_name, that's why I said `assignment_set`, edited it to say `assignments`.